# How to apply filter condition during Pandas Merge operation but retain them in the result DF?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, left-join

I'm trying to do something with pandas equivalent to the following SQL command:

```
select *
from tableA as A
left join tableB as B
on A.key = B.key and substr(A.value,1,2) not in ('something', 'something else')
```

As you can see in the sql query above, A.value have a filter condition applied during the join, but since it's a left join, the on condition not in criteria does not persist to the result dataset, it only applies during the join operation, such that the join operation will not consider any rows fulfilling the A.value not in ('something', 'something else') criteria.

I tried the following python code, but it results in filtering out the A.value rows from the result dataset, I need all the rows via the left join, but i don't want the merge operation on the rows as specified by the a.value not in condition, just like the SQL statement logic above.

```
df_output = df_input1[~df_input1['value'].str[:2].isin(['something', 'something_else'])].merge(df_input2, left_on = 'key', right_on = 'key', how='left')
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think if you filter `df_input2` instead of `df_input1` you'll get the result you want

Comment: @mitoRibo How would i be able to filter df_input2 though? The a.value column isn't used as the join key, otherwise I can see filtering on df_input2 to cause df_input1 not be able to join on those values, that would work, but in this case df_input1's value column is completely independent of df_input2, I just don't want the rows meeting the value not in criteria to join to df_input2.

Comment: thanks for explaining, you're right I didn't understand what you were trying to do

Comment: @mitoRibo no problem! Actually it's funny, I had a different instance where on a.key = b.key and a.key is not null. In this case I did filter on b.key.notna() to basically achieve the a.key is not null criteria, because input_b in this case does not matter, as we are doing left join, and if b.key is not null, a.key has to not be null for the join to work. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hacky, but the idea is to create a new column for joining in df1 and to only fill in this column for rows that you want to merge with:

```
import pandas as pd

df_input1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit':['apple','banana','mango'],
    'quantity':[3,4,5],
})

df_input2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit':['apple','banana','mango'],
    'in_stock':[True,False,True],
})

minimum_quantity = 4
ind = df_input1['quantity'].ge(minimum_quantity)
df_input1.loc[ind, 'merge_column'] = df_input1.loc[ind, 'fruit']

merge_filtered_fruits = df_input1.merge(
    df_input2,
    left_on = 'merge_column',
    right_on = 'fruit',
    how = 'left'
).drop(columns=['merge_column'])

print(merge_filtered_fruits)
```

Output:

```
  fruit_x  quantity fruit_y in_stock
0   apple         3     NaN      NaN
1  banana         4  banana    False
2   mango         5   mango     True
```

I'm curious what a better method could be

Comment: This is actually pretty neat, even though it's a bit of a hack. Worked nicely for me, I don't mind using hacks like these. Thank you!

Comment: great! I'd suggest leaving the question open for a day at least to see if anyone else can provide a less hacky answer :)

Comment: yes I was planning on doing that :), since I saw your ending remark suggesting there could be other less hacky methods out there. Have a good one.